# Showing ClickOnce deployment version on WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, clickonce

I'm deploying now a WPF c# project and want to put the **clickonce version** (rather than the assembly or product version) on the screen title.
I used to do it in Win form application in the following way. But it seems that it is not the way in WPF applications. I searched on Google but didn't find anything. Please help.

```
    if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
        lblVer.Text = "V" + ad.CurrentVersion.ToString();
    }
    else
        lblVer.Text = "V" + Application.ProductVersion.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK,
I found the problem.
I had to add reference to `System.Deployment` 
That is why I couldn't use it. This dll is for winforms also.

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
public static Version GetPublishedVersion()
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    Assembly asmCurrent = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string executePath = new Uri(asmCurrent.GetName().CodeBase).LocalPath;

    xmlDoc.Load(executePath + ".manifest");
    string retval = string.Empty;
    if (xmlDoc.HasChildNodes)
    {
        retval = xmlDoc.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[0].Attributes.GetNamedItem("version").Value.ToString();
    }
    return new Version(retval);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What error do you get? There's no difference in the ClickOnce API's between Windows Forms and WPF. It is not dependent upon any UI framework.

Did you remember to add a reference to System.Deployment.dll?

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Deployment.Application;

namespace Utils
{
    public class ClickOnce
    {
        public static Version GetPublishedVersion()
        {
            return ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed 
                ? ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion 
                : System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
        }
    }
}
```

If you get an error about `System.Deployment.Application`, then Solution > Project > References > Add Reference > Assemblies > Framework > System.Deployment.

Do *not* parse the assembly XML for this information; you're relying on undocumented behaviour which simply happens to work 'for now'.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is similar to @Engin, but uses XPath.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("...");
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("asmv1", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1");
string xPath = "/asmv1:assembly/asmv1:assemblyIdentity/@version";
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xPath, ns);
string version = node.Value;
```