# How to get the publish version of a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I want my WPF application publish version. I tried using the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591368/showing-clickonce-deployment-version-on-wpf-application) question. It works but the problem is we can manually change the values there. I want to know how many times my project was actually published (don't need version number. Just how many times did I publish my application). Can this be done?

Comment: don't know if this will help, but you could count the number of sub-folders under "Application Files" from your publish root folder. the downside of this is you could overwrite with the same version (e.g. publish twice with the same version number will only get 1 sub-folder there).

Answer (score 14):

Using Click Once, each time you publish, Visual Studio will change the number automatically. It will increment the value each time you publish. Your problem is that you have manually changed the number. The solution is to publish and just let Visual Studio update the value... you should notice that your project needs to be saved once you have published. This is because Visual Studio just incremented the value for you.

---

UPDATE >>>

If you want to access the published version from code (which you *should* have made clear in your question), then you can use this code, but you have to ensure that the application is network deployed first... that means that it has actually been published, so it won't work while you are debugging. Try this:

```
private string GetPublishedVersion()
{
    if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        return System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.
            CurrentVersion.ToString();
    }
    return "Not network deployed";
}
```

Comment: May be you are thinking that I am one who downvoted your answer. Its not me. Anyways I will give your approach a try.

Comment: No, I wasn't thinking that at all. Either way, you really *should* make *all* of your requirements *clear* in your question, without relying on users to follow your links. You didn't actually mention anywhere in your question that you wanted to do this in code.

Comment: Note: This requires a reference to the System.Deployment assembly.

Answer (score 10):

You may be confused by 2 sets of numbers. Please note that you can set version of your WPF app in **TWO different places**:

1. Project Properties / Publish tab / **Publish Version**
2. `AssemblyVersion` declared in **AssemblyInfo.cs** file, which you can find if you expand Project Properties node in Solution Explorer.

They are similar in the sense that they both provides 4 numbers: major, minor, build and revision. The difference is that `Publish Version` is **only available** if the app was actually Published (i.e. Installed). It is not available in your debug session nor if you just copy the executable to another machine and run it there. SO, if you just need to track version of your EXE file, use **AssemblyInfo.cs**.

Correspondingly, to read the data use the following code:

---

1 To read **Publish version** (declared in Publish tab)

```
using System.Deployment.Application;
ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString();
```

Note that in this case: a) you need to add reference to `System.Deployment` assembly, b) if the app was not deployed, it won't work.

---

2 To read **Assembly Version** (declared in AssemblyInfo.cs)

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

This one always works.

Comment: where do i add this functionality (publish version)? Do I add it to main page cs file or App.xaml.cs?

Answer (score 4):

Universal solution if we get application version from not startup assembly:

```
var version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version;
string appVersion = $"{version.Major}.{version.Minor}";
```

GetEntryAssembly give version of startup project.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var obj=Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
    string version= string.Format("Application Version {0}.{1}", obj.Build, obj.Revision);  

OR

 string version= string.Format("Application Version {0}.{1}", obj.Major, obj.Minor);
```

whichever properties suits you.

Comment: This just returned 1.0.0.0 for me... not quite what I needed

Comment: This is the Assembly version, not the Publish version.

Comment: This code returns assembly version. We are searching for publish version